# What is the function of frequency resolution in multisim

Tags: modulation, multisim

In this circuit, noticed if the frequency is set to be the same as source frequency, the display will show a constant peak. The modulation index is 0.6.
[image]

However, if the resolution frequency is set to frequency other than 2kHz, it shown a varying peak with different shape.
[image]

By referring to the [guide in multisim](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/375482B-01/multisim/usingspectrumanalyzer/) for spectrum analyzer, it said

> Resolution freq.—This is initially set to a minimum value of D f = f_end/1024. You can change it to a greater value and observe the spectrum. You must select the frequency resolution so that the frequencies are integer multiples of frequency resolutions.

However, I am still not able to grasp the concept on what does it actually mean. Appreciate if someone can give an explanation or link regarding this.

Comment: This is how FFT-based analysis works. Were you expecting something different?

Comment: As I haven't learn fft, am not aware this is relevant to fft. Thanks for pointing out so I can seek the Information I want be refer to fft topic.